# Excel: ClearContent preserving formulas

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA is there a way to safely use `Range("A1:B2").ClearContent` without deleting the existent formulas in the cells?

Just to make my scenario clearer: I'm pulling fresh data from the database and just want to erase everything on the sheet but not the formulas because those will resolve some data in other fields with vlookups.

Comment: Then what are you trying to clear?

Comment: Just the values of the Cells: numbers, dates and text

Comment: The formulas _create_ the values.

Comment: So ok, assume that you have some formatting on the cells for example you want a cell formatted as date and ClearContent is going to delete even that formatting. How would you prevent this?

Comment: Your question still makes no sense.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what makes no sense in my question? I've tried to explain myself already

Comment: @SLacks Excel distinguish between formulas and constants. That is the main reason behind using "=" to enter formulas. And yes, you can select one or the other. See @Dick's answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the SpecialCells property to get only the constant values.

```
Sub RemoveConstants()

    Dim rConstants As Range

    Set rConstants = Sheet1.Range("A1:B2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    rConstants.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that if no cells in the range actually have values, Excel throws an error "No cells were found" in response to
    Set rConstants = Sheet1.Range("A1:B2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

Comment: Add a `On Error Resume Next` at the start of the sub to avoid the "No cells were found" error.